# how to change values of a list based on index of another list in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

I have the following list

```
I=[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
   [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
   [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
   [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
   [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

I would like to replace some elements of 0 by 1 in list I based on index of nother list S

```
S=[2,2,1]
```

Note that :
The first element in list S corresponds to the first column in the list I, 
2nd  element in list S corresponds to the 2nd column in the list I
3rd element in list S corresponds to the 3rd column in the list I

the output like this

```
IS=[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],  
    [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],     
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],     
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
```

The output i want to get is as follows:
 starting by colmn1 which corresponds to the first element in list S,  since S[0]=2 , we access the first two rows in colmn1 of the list I and replace 0 with 1  diagonally.
then we get

```
 colmn1      colmn2      colmn3
[[**1, 0, 0]**, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 1 
[**[0, 1, 0]**, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 2
```

Then move to the second element of S which corresponds the colmn2 in list I, since S[1]= 2  then we access the next two rows in colmn2 and replace the 0 elements diagonally in these next two rows.

```
 colmn1      colmn2      colmn3
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 1 
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 2
[[0, 0, 0], **[1, 0, 0]**, [0, 0, 0]], row 3
[[0, 0, 0], **[0, 1, 0]**, [0, 0, 0]], row 4
```

finally, go to last element in S ( corresponding last colmn in list I), since we have S[2]=1 so that  we access the next row and replace 0 with 1 in the diagonal direction to get

```
 colmn1      colmn2      colmn3
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 1 
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 2
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 3
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]], row 4 
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], **[1, 0, 0]**], row 5
```

I hope the explanation is clear

Comment: @A Azab could you please explain the output part. looks unclear

Comment: @PythonBang I hope it became clear now,Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use:

```
cols = zip(*I)

offset = 0
for l, n in zip(cols, S):
    for i in range(n):
        l[offset][i] = 1
        offset += 1

print(I)
```

output:

```
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
```